# Sails.js app variable data not being shown in view even though logs show it

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

I have a simple sales app in which in a controller I am querying a database. Retrieving the results, doing some manipulation on the data with async.each function and then sending the array to the view.

Even though my logs are showing a the data in the array my view is receiving a blank array.

```
"index": function(req, res, next) {
    Sales.find().sort("createdAt DESC").done(function(err, sales) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("An error has occured. :(");
        } else {
            if (!sales) {
                req.session.flash = {
                    err: {
                        message: "You have no billing as of now.",
                        style: "alert-info"
                    }
                }
            } else {

                var bills = [];

                async.eachSeries(sales, function(thisSale, callback) {
                    if (!bills[thisSale.billingNo]) {
                        bills[thisSale.billingNo] = {
                            id: thisSale.billingNo,
                            createdAt: thisSale.createdAt,
                            total: (thisSale.quantity * thisSale.price),
                            location: thisSale.location,
                        };
                    } else {
                        bills[thisSale.billingNo].total += (thisSale.quantity * thisSale.price);
                    }
                    callback();
                }, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Something went wrong !');
                        exit();
                    } else {
                        res.send({
                            billing: bills
                        });
                        console.log("=====\nBILL\n=====\n", bills);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
},
```

I replaced res.view with res.send to debug my code, on the client side I only receive this:

```
{
  "billing": []
}
```

Although the console logs show :

```
=====
BILL
=====
 [ '53b95fdc1f7a596316f37af0': { id: '53b95fdc1f7a596316f37af0',
    createdAt: Sun Jul 06 2014 20:10:28 GMT+0530 (IST),
    total: 6497,
    location: 'Location A' },
  '53b8f7c81f7a596316f37aed': { id: '53b8f7c81f7a596316f37aed',
    createdAt: Sun Jul 06 2014 12:46:24 GMT+0530 (IST),
    total: 6497,
    location: 'Location A' } ]
```

Can someone help me figure out what im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to debug the issue and found i was unable to access bills[0] then using a forEach loop on the array bills and found that it was unable to run the for each loop.

On changing the variable bills from an array to an object the problem was fixed.

Im not entirely sure why this happened, or why i was having trouble adding variables to an array, but changing

```
var bills = [];
```

to

```
var bills = {};
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're coming from a PHP background where "associative arrays" are a valid type?  In Javascript, arrays are only meant to be indexed by *integers*, e.g.

```
bills[0] = "something";
```

This is somewhat confused by the fact that Javascript arrays are, like all non-primitive types, *object instances*, so that they can have arbitrary properties added to them:

```
bills.abc = 123;
bills["some arbitrary string"] = 555;
```

But you're strongly discouraged from using arrays this way, for many reasons including:

- `JSON.stringify()` will ignore non-integer indexes, which is why you were having the issue in your question.  Sails (along with many other libraries) uses `JSON.stringify()` to serialize Javascript objects for transport.
- Javascript arrays have several reserved keys such as `length`, `push` and `pop` which you can't assign values to.
- An array's `length()` method won't count non-integer keys.
- It's just confusing to work with arrays this way; that's what plain objects (declared with `{}`) are for!

Hopefully this explains why changing to `var bills = {}` makes everything work.